# Referencing scripts in class vs in method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a super basic question, i'm sure, but I can't find an answer. So I notice that whenever another script is referenced at the top of a class you have to drag it into the Unity inspector slot as well or else it will return a null reference exception. For Example:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
   public ScriptExample1 scriptexample1;

   public void Method()
   {
      scriptexample1.score++;
   }
}
```

However, if the script is referenced as a method parameter you do not have to drag it into the inspector slot. For Example:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{


   public void Method(ScriptExample2 scriptexample2)
   {
      scriptexample2.score++;
   }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why ScriptExample1 needs the script to be dragged into the inspector slot and ScriptExample2 doesn't?

Thank you,

Comment: Depends. The second can work if there is a static member of the referenced class.

Answer (score 0):

Object references need to come from *somewhere*.

When you define a public field, Unity lists it in the inspector window, where dragging a component will set that reference for you through the designer.

Another way to initialize a field's reference is to fetch a component in your `OnStart` callback, and explicitly set it - this works by traversing the GameObject components and finding one of the correct type (not finding the component might throw an error right there, or leave the field `null` to blow up later, I'm not sure):

```
public SomeComponent someComponent;

public void OnStart()
{
    someComponent = GetComponent<SomeComponent>();
}
```

caveat: air-code from memory for illustrative purposes

When you receive a component as a method parameter, you're deferring the responsibility of this initialization to the caller: if the caller does not initialize it or otherwise passes a `null` reference, consuming it will throw a `NullReferenceException` all the same.